# Can I say "something in your vibe" as an alternative idiom to "to vibe with something."

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, slogan

I am searching for a slogan for my website named "Vibeware", and as you might have guessed, it is about software (the name itself being a result of playing around with the first letters in my name parts until it made sense).

In a dictionary, I stumbled up that there is an idiom going like "to vibe with somebody.", which means that you understand this somebody very good and are in a good relationship with him.

I thus wanted to use the slogan "Software which vibes with you", but that is a bit long and also sounds dull because of "which" and "with" so near beyond each other.

Is it possible to rephrase it to "Software in your vibe"? I am not sure if the idiom is still recognizable or if it sounds uncomfortable to native English speakers.

Comment: Why is it so hard to type somebody or something when you can type the rest of the sentence fully?

Comment: I'm familiar with the expression "to jive with something (or someone)".  I've never heard "to vibe with something (or someone)".  An idiomatic expression using "vibe" would be "I'm getting weird vibes from him/her".  Then, of course, there's the Beach Boys (60's, US) famous song "Good Vibrations".

Comment: @SrJoven: That is how it is written in the dictionary. I do not do that if I am not discussing language syntax.

Comment: "Software in your vibe" makes me want to go looking for a disk in my Pontiac. Just saying.

Comment: Did you already discount wording the slogan as "Software that vibes with you?" That flows better than using "which" in AmE, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

As a native speaker of AmE, I wouldn't use this.

Might I suggest *Software **on Your Wavelength*** as an alternative?  *On your wavelength* is a reasonably common idiom with some of the same connotations, and it is a much better match for your desired sentence structure. In my opinion, it still pairs well with "Vibeware" (it's a little less direct connection, but it's more elegant).

The justification: *Vibe* is from vibrations, which have a wavelength --if two people are on the same wavelength, they vibe together.

Comment: I think this sounds best, since I should forget about using vibe as a verb, as many people only know it as a noun.

Answer (score 1):

In American English, vibe is strictly a noun.

> a feeling that someone or something gives you ([source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vibe)) [other](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vibe) [sources](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Vibe) [agree](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vibe).

British English, however, seems to have a verb definition, too, which I had never heard of before now:

> Transmit or give out (a feeling or atmosphere) ([source](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vibe))

So I guess whether or not you can "vibe with" someone depends on your side of the pond.  It would certainly strike me odd as an AmEng speaker.

Incidentally, the source you originally cited, [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=vibe), equates "vibe with" with "die gleiche Wellenlänge haben".  I would personally translate that as 'on the same wavelength', which correlates with Chris Sunami's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you're looking for is "jibe" or "gibe," not "jive." "Jive" is a type of music--typically jazz. It also can mean "nonsense"--not a good thing to associate with your product or brand! To answer your question, "in your jibe" does not make much sense to me. I'd just go with "software that jibes." You could build on that to brand in different ways: It jibes with your systems. It jibes with your business goals. It jibes with....

Comment: The OP's word is "vibe", not jive.  FWIW, I guess I've been using "jive" to mean "jibe" for a very long time now! lol!

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking for "jibe" or "jive."  *Vibe* is a reasonably common slang term, and I've definitely heard the idiom "to *vibe* with [someone]."

Comment: The dictionary I got it from is dict.cc. I also never heard of this idiom before but was of course positively surprised to see it as a choice for a slogan. But as long as noone other than the dictionary knows, it would be quite useless. I added an explanation why I would prefer something with "vibe" in the slogan, since the company is a result of some lyrical mess of my name parts ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Vibeware - software in phase with your unique vibe.  'in phase with' is another variation of 'on your wavelength', except that 'phase' has the technical meaning that all the peaks and valleys of the compared waveforms line up. (The opposite is '90 degrees out of phase' which means the peaks of one wave line up with the valleys of the other wave. Two copies of the same waveform '90 degrees out of phase' cancel each other out.  Two copies of the same waveform 'in phase' amplify each other. Any phase relationship between 'in' and '90 degrees out' cancels each waveform a relative amount).  With this slogan you would be saying that Vibeware's products amplify their customers' vibes.  In other words, "we make software that helps you be more like you".

Answer (score 0):

I think "resonate" is the word you are looking for.

> "Resonate" means to reverberate, or echo, as in sound. If something resonates with you it means that a topic or emotion someone else has mentioned or experienced keeps coming back to you, keeps echoing in your head, because it means something personal to you as well.

So, resonate is related to vibe or vibrations

So a slogan might be: "Start resonating with Vibeware!"
Or "You'll resonate with Vibeware!"